# Calling converter's Convert() method everytime on mouse over WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, ivalueconverter

I would like to call the converter's Convert method though there is no value change in the source. Now it is calling first time only. Is there any way to achieve this?

I know that convert method will not call every time unless there is a change is the source.

```
 public class ElementNameToDrawingBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Method converts colors to brush.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">value to convert</param>
        /// <param name="targetType">target type</param>
        /// <param name="parameter">param for convert</param>
        /// <param name="culture">culture info instance</param>
        /// <returns>converted brush</returns>
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DrawingBrush settedBrush = null;
            var shape = value as Shape;

            if (shape == null || parameter == null)
            {
                return value;
            }

            settedBrush = shape.Fill as DrawingBrush;
            return GetIconBrush(settedBrush, parameter as Brush);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is to provide the new brush for the image
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="settedBrush">settedBrush</param>
        /// <param name="brushColor">brushColor</param>
        /// <returns>DrawingBrush</returns>
        public static DrawingBrush GetIconBrush(DrawingBrush settedBrush, Brush brushColor)
        {
            DrawingBrush newBrush = null;

            if (settedBrush != null && brushColor != null)
            {
                newBrush = settedBrush.Clone();

                foreach (var geometry in ((DrawingGroup)newBrush.Drawing).Children)
                {
                    GeometryDrawing geometryDrawing = geometry as GeometryDrawing;

                    if (geometryDrawing != null)
                    {
                        if (geometryDrawing.Pen != null)
                        {
                            if (geometryDrawing.Pen.Brush != null)
                            {
                                geometryDrawing.Pen.Brush = brushColor;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (geometryDrawing.Brush != null)
                        {
                            geometryDrawing.Brush = brushColor;
                        }
                    }

                    DrawingGroup drawingGroup = geometry as DrawingGroup;

                    if (drawingGroup != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var geometryInner in drawingGroup.Children)
                        {
                            GeometryDrawing geometryDrawingChild = geometryInner as GeometryDrawing;

                            if (geometryDrawingChild != null)
                            {
                                if (geometryDrawingChild.Pen != null)
                                {
                                    geometryDrawingChild.Pen.Brush = brushColor;
                                }
                                else if (geometryDrawingChild.Brush != null)
                                {
                                    geometryDrawingChild.Brush = brushColor;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return newBrush;
            }

            return settedBrush;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert back implementation
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">value to convert back</param>
        /// <param name="targetType">target type</param>
        /// <param name="parameter">param for convert</param>
        /// <param name="culture">culture info instance</param>
        /// <returns>fallback object</returns>
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
             throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource CustomButton}" Content="{Binding MyContent}" ImageContent="{StaticResource  SystemResetNormal}"/>

<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="CustomButton">
        <Border Background="Pink" Height="80" Width="70">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle x:Name="buttonRectangle" Fill="{TemplateBinding ImageContent}" Height="60" Width="40" Loaded="Rectangle_Loaded" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="ContentTxt" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="buttonRectangle" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding ElementName=buttonRectangle,
                    Converter={StaticResource ElementNameToBrushConverter},
                    ConverterParameter={StaticResource BAquamarine}}" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

I need to call Convert method every time when i mouse over it.

Comment: You mean you actually want to change the TextBlock's Foreground when IsMouseOver changes? Note that it seems pointless to use a Converter for a Brush Binding that always returns the same value. Just directly assign a Brush resource.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But i do not want to assign a brush directly. Let's say if i change the text dynamically and do the mouse over again, convert method will not call to apply foreground color.

Comment: You mean you change the ConverterParameter?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that. What does that have to do with IsMouseOver?

Comment: Could you please see my xaml code above i just replaced code snippet. Where i want to change the icon color.

Comment: Change the content and ImageContent, then do the mouse over, the convert method will not call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind to `ImageContent` instead of `buttonRectangle`:

```
<Setter TargetName="buttonRectangle" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding ImageContent,
                Converter={StaticResource ElementNameToBrushConverter},
                ConverterParameter={StaticResource BAquamarine}}" />
```

Then the converter should be invoked whenever you set the `ImageContent` property provided that you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly.

In your converter, you should then cast the actual value to a `Brush` instead of a `Shape`:

```
var settleBrush = value as DrawingBrush;
...
```